# How to begin stylising a game

Tags: graphics, cocos2d-iphone, assets

I'm currently in the late stages of development for a platform-esque iPhone game and am beginning to look into the graphics. Being a developer through-and-through, I have limited design skills and my budget can't stretch too far to pay a designer to build all the assets.

I've noticed a few games recently that are heavily styled which helps with the look of the game (consistency etc...) and keep the graphics required down to a minimum. The best example of this I can find is the iOS game "Contre Jour".

So, I'm wondering how I can go about a) picking & designing a style that will work with the game and b) implementing it within the Cocos2d environment.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I think you might be underestimating the "graphics required" for a game like "Contre Jour". Perhaps you can get an artist interested if your game play is good. This question is very broad. You're asking how to pick an art style, which of course depends on what you want and how to implement it, which depends on what style you pick.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a developer "through and through" reconsider hiring an artist, and don't be afraid to look in non-traditional places.

I know when it comes time for me to throw away the place holder graphics and get more serious, I will be going to the Art Departments of colleges in my area.  I know a few Art Students who would love to help with the design of a video game, and build their portfolio at the same time.

Also, talk with a Graphic Design Teacher.  They might use your game as a project for their students.  You get art, the students build portfolios, and the professor gets a final exam.

Comment: It can often be good to try just replacing your placeholders with styled graphics gathered from the internet. Use these to give you an idea about what direction you would like to go in and to see how different tones and styles feel. You can also show them to friends and see what they think. I find this helps to build an idea in my head which you can then ask an artist to help you create.